# Strange output from matplotlib mathtext

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, fedora

I tried to use mathtext to get a specially rendered figure title, but it failed. Instead of my test title it just printed cryptic characters. What am I doing wrong?

- Operating System: Fedora release 18 (Spherical Cow)
- Python and matplotlib are installed from official repositories via yum

Here's the (full) code:

```
import sys
print sys.version             # prints:
                              # 2.7.3 (default, Aug  9 2012, 17:23:57)
                              # [GCC 4.7.1 20120720 (Red Hat 4.7.1-5)]
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.__version__  # prints:
                              # 1.2.0

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,5])
plt.title(r"$1.2345$")
plt.show()
```

Here's the output image:
[image: strange title rendering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly it was a font-related thing. Found an old [bug-report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=562421) to address the issue.

A suggestion in [one of the comments](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=562421#c31) was to install the package `lyx-fonts`. This solved the problem for me.

---

Another workaround [proposed here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=908717#c1) is to configure the mathtext rendering like this (at the top of the script):

```
plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = "stix"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using RedHat, CentOS or some other Fedora derivative, you may be seeing the bug described here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=562421

Try installing the "stix" font package (on CentOS/RedHat this is "stix-fonts"). The delete your ~/.matplotlib/fontlist.cache file. Next, re-run your system's font-cache script, probably  "fc-cache -f -s -v".

Now, change the matplotlibrc settings (either via a ~./matplotlib/matplotlibrc file or a matplotlibrc file in the same directory as your script) as follows:

```
mathtext.fontset : stix 
mathtext.fallback_to_cm : True
mathtext.default : it
```

I'd love to know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. stix-fonts were already installed, configuring matplotlibrc to use them didn't help. But see my [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14717782/1025391).

Comment: interestingly, when I use the matplotlibrc file to define the mathtext fontset the `show()` method does not show anything anymore, i.e., no window opens. maybe another bug.